# New Prebuilt Drone flipping on takeoff

Tags: quadcopters

I have a small quadcopter drone, immediately on takeoff it flips upside down, this happens all the time.

What could be a potential problem?

Edit: It is prebuilt and bought from a shop and has never flown

Comment: Is this a hobby-grade drone or a "toy" drone because the answers could be different depending on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additionally to the options listed above, looking into whether or not:

- You may have a reversed or upside down prop
- Motor spinning wrong way
- FC board orientation isn’t what it thinks it is

Answer (score 14):

There are several things that can be causing this with different likelihoods.

The first thing to check is - are your propellers on correctly? It is an easy mistake to make and always worth a check.

The next thing to check is that all of your motors are working correctly. Start by spinning each of the motors by hand and see if anything feels obviously wrong, for example, a magnet out of place. If nothing feels wrong, remove the props and individually spin up the motors in Betaflight to test them. Make sure that they spin the direction that betaflight shows in the configurator.

The next port of call is your gyro. Plug your quad into Betaflight or whatever firmware you use and move it around - does the virtual representation of the quad match up with your movements in real life? If not, that is almost certainly the cause.

If all of these have failed, swap two of your motors and see if the quad flips in the same direction. If the problem follows the motor, you have a faulty motor. If the problem stays in the same place, you have a faulty ESC.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this recently with 2 different BNF's. One I had the props on the wrong way! The other I needed to recalibrate the accelerometer. You can either use Betaflight to recall, or the stick commands (Google them and keep a copy in your flight bag).

Answer (score 4):

Here are some solutions:

- **Make sure nothing is stuck inside the propellers** and that all 4 are spinning reportedly, a faulty one could mean a flip
- **Same speed** - make sure all the propellers are running at the same speed
- **Reconnect your controller**

Answer (score 4):

Alternative Solutions:

- **The accelerometer must be calibrated** (make sure that you set the drone on a flat surface so it can calibrate before takeoff)
- **Propeller orientation** (If all of the motors work and appear to be spinning in the right direction, make sure that the propellers are put on correctly)
- **Practice** (If everything else is fine, make sure that you move the controls gently and understand how to fly a quadcopter)